# How to convert USD to ETH?

Tags: javascript, react

I have created a simple CodeSandbox project to convert ETH to USD. however now I want to convert USD to ETH also. I think it seems to be there is an issue in my USD to ETH logic. It gives me the wrong output. Can anyone give me the correct logic it will help me to understand what happened in my code?

I'm using [Coinbase Digital Currency API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-currencies)

[Coinbase converter](https://www.coinbase.com/converter/eth/usd)

**api.js file**

```
export const GetUSDExchangeRate = async () => {
  var requestOptions = { method: "GET", redirect: "follow" };
  return fetch("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=ETH", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {return(result.data.rates.USD)})
    .catch((error) => {return("error", error)});
}

export const GetETHExchangeRate = async () => {
  var requestOptions = { method: "GET", redirect: "follow" };
  return fetch("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {return(result.data.rates.ETH)})
    .catch((error) => {return("error", error)});
}
```

**ETH to USD covert part**

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
  {(ethPrice * usdExRate).toFixed(2)} USD
</Grid>
```

**USD to ETH part**

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
  {(usdPrice / ethExRate).toFixed(2)} ETH
</Grid>
```

Here is my full code part I had done.

[image: Edit converter]

Comment: What do you mean by "It gives me the wrong output."? Can you give an example of the wrong output?